# MockClassLoader cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl

Tags: java, maven, powermock, powermockito

I am in the middle of migrating a project into Java9, The Tests start failing after I switched to the new Java version, it seems like PowerMock is trying to access some classes it does not have access to.

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.973 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.Test
initializationError(com.Test)  Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl
```

**maven-surefire-plugin**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.groovy</include>
            <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
        </includes>
        <forkMode>always</forkMode>
        <argLine>--add-modules java.xml.bind</argLine>
        <argLine>--add-modules java.activation</argLine>
        <argLine>--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --illegal-access=warn</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**powermock dependency**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: java11 "duplicate": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966897/powermock-java-11

Answer (score 65):

I had a test dependency on a third-party jar which used powermock. In order to resolve this error, I had to add:

```
@PowerMockIgnore("jdk.internal.reflect.*")
```

To the class that is tested with `powermock`

Comment: but still I am facing some issue                                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.Class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @506c589e

Comment: @SandeepKamath or Saif Masadeh how did you get around this? I am facing same problem with jdk11. and ignoring jdk.internal.reflect.* does not works for me.

Comment: @mohdshoaib I have the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: hey @Wenaro, I had to add jdk.internal.reflect.* in the ignore list. But also had to update my JaCoCo plugin version and if it's a multi-module project then made fork-count as zero for the surefire plugin. Essentially different thing might work for your uses. Adding entire ignore list if that helps:
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.sax.*", "org.w3c.dom.*",
    "org.springframework.context.*", "org.apache.log4j.*", "org.apache.commons.logging.*",
    "org.jacoco.*", "jdk.internal.reflect.*"})

Answer (score 17):

It is an (currently) [open issue @powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/901), but for Java 9 this should work:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.0</version> <!-- or higher, correspondning to powermock-version -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version> <!-- or higher -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version> <!-- or higher -->
</dependency>
```

See: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/901#issuecomment-385533096

---

With Java 11, [Mosheer-Ahmad](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/901#issuecomment-510922977) managed to run his tests, with:

1. the above dependencies,
2. an additional dependency on `org.javassist javassist 3.24.1-GA test`and
3. this (test base) class/annotations:

   ```
   @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
   @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.", 
     "javax.xml.", "org.xml.", "org.w3c.dom.",
     "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.", "javax.activation.*"})
   public class PowerMockitoBaseRunner {

   }
   ```

   .

Comment: best answered by the response from the "main contributor" of powermock: " thekingnothing commented on 20 Apr 2018
 Hi,

There is some sort of supporting JKD 9 in beta versions of PowerMock 2.0. I’m not going to implement supporting Java 9 or 10 in the PowerMock 1.x

Right now the project is in frozen state because I do not have enough time. I hope I will be able to return back to project soon.

Best Regards,
Arthur Zagretdinov
..." from: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/901

Comment: If you are (still) stuck with that, please also try [this comment](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/901#issuecomment-510922977).

Comment: yes, upgrading version of `powermockito` solve. FYI, I am on `jdk 9`

Comment: is work for me this solution but i have add * like this:
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*",
      "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*",
      "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*"})

Comment: thx, @sghaierali! I think the contents of `@PowerMockIgnore` are also somewhat "custom", everyone has to find his (own, minimum) "workaround set".

Answer (score 6):

Just to re-iterate the very good point made by sghaier ali.

Adding * to the ignored classes solved the issue.

changes done are:

- The following dependencies in build.gradle:

  ```
  testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3'
  testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.5'
  testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.5'
  ```
- annotating the specific class with:

  ```
  @PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*",
      "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*", "javax.activation.*"})
  ```

Comment: I believe that the ignoring of these specific packages seems more correct before reflection seems key to mocking.  When I include this ignore, 2 of my 3 instances of the error go away - I still have one instance of the error.  If I simply ignore reflection this is flagged (i.e., the kind of behavior central to mocking):
`when(mockBatchHandler.handleMessageType(any(), any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(taskMap);`

Answer (score 5):

As @smac89 mentioned all I had to do is ignore the offending package.

By annotating my test class with `@PowerMockIgnore("jdk.internal.reflect.*")`

My Maven dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Java version:

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run it using Oracle JDK 1.8

Comment: As suggested by you, changed to java 8 and it worked fine.
I am using Ubuntu, so ran command and picked java 8 version 
sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: On WIndows set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the path to Java 8 JDK